# Create a matrix based on names

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create a matrix using characters. The characters are names of vectors in a data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
colnames(df) <- c("a1","b1","c1","d1")
a <- paste("df$",names(df), sep = "")
```

How can I use these characters to reference the data frame and take the data in the vector to a matrix? Something like:

```
as.matrix(cbind(df$a1,df$b1))
```

but instead of me writing `df$a1,df$b1` these names come from `a`

Comment: Is `as.matrix(df)` what you are looking for?

Comment: In the real case I don't want all of the vectors in `df` only a select few

Comment: Just use `as.matrix(df[,vec])` where `vec` is either a numeric vector whose values are the column indices you want to keep or a character vector with the names of the columns.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks

Comment: @nicola please post an answer, as the situation here is getting worse by the minute.

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Lol, done as requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
as.matrix(df[,vec])
```

where `vec` is either a numeric vector whose values are the column indices you want to keep or a character vector with the names of the columns.